# Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have a simple jsf login application.

My login.jsp is

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>

<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSF Login Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Enter Login ID: " /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="id" value="#{LoginBean.loginid}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Enter Password: " /></td>
                    <td><h:inputSecret id="pwd" value="#{LoginBean.pwd}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{LoginBean.CheckValidUser}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

My LoginBean is

```
public class LoginBean{
String loginid;
String pwd;

public LoginBean(){}

public String getLoginid(){
    return loginid;
}
public void setLoginid(String loginid){
    this.loginid = loginid;
}
public String getPwd(){
    return pwd;
}
public void setPwd(String pwd){
    this.pwd = pwd;
}
public String CheckValidUser()
{
    if(loginid.equals("username") && pwd.equals("password"))
    {
        return "success";
    }
    else
    {
        return "fail";
    }
}
}
```

and my web.xml is

```
<web-app>

<display-name>JSFLoginAppln</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

There seems to be no problem while deploying as its not throwing any exception while deploying. But when I run on JBOSS server, it throws the following exception

```
13:08:10,800 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1855)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1672)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(login_jsp.java:99)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:76)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can anyone please help me out in fixing this....

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you forget to mark your LoginBean as ManagedBean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344797/java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-find-facescontext-jsf-1-2-primefaces-tom

Comment: @Mr.J4mes: I have marked it. <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>LoginBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.bean.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

Comment: This is not the problem. Read the duplicate question link of Mithun for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I just removed `jsf-api` and `jsf-imp` from my project lib and inserted

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

in `web.xml`, because i let Eclipse run time environment `jBoss` on creation of the project.